# A "sort-of strict" separation between two disjoint closed, convex sets

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, analysis, convex-analysis

**Question:**

Suppose $X$ is a closed convex nonempty set in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Define $W := \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n \mid x_i = x_i' \; \forall i \in I\}$ for some $x' \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $I \subseteq \{1,\dots,n\}$.

If $X \cap W = \emptyset$, is there a hyperplane $H := \{x\in \mathbb{R}^n \mid v^\intercal x = \alpha \}$ such that
$$
X \subseteq \{x\in \mathbb{R}^n \mid v^\intercal x \leq \alpha \}
$$
and
$$
W \subseteq \{x\in \mathbb{R}^n \mid v^\intercal x > \alpha \}
$$
?

---

**Where this comes from:**

I'm looking at an algorithm that may run into this type of situation in each iteration. If it does, one needs to find a polyhedron $P$ that such that $X \subseteq P$ and $P \cap W = \emptyset$. I'm trying to show that this is guaranteed.

If there is such a hyperplane $H$ as in the question, I'd just set $P := \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n \mid v^\intercal x \leq \alpha\}$.

---

**Thoughts:**

I'm not sure what to call this type of separation, but it's not covered by any of the typical separating hyperplane theorems that I've seen.

If $X$ were also bounded (and therefore compact), strict separation would hold. But I can't make that assumption about $X$.

I would have just asked this about generic closed convex nonempty sets $X$ and $W$, but then I realized that if $X = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid x_2 \geq \textrm{e}^{x_1} \}$ and $W = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid x_2 \leq 0\}$ then there would be no such hyperplane. (Though there would be if the definitions of $X$ and $W$ were switched.)

Comment: Look up the Hahn-Banach Separation theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a counter-example to the statement as given.  Define: 
$$ X = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : y \geq e^x\}$$
$$ W = \{(x,0) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : x \in \mathbb{R}\}$$
Suppose there is a nonzero vector $(u,v)$ and real number $\alpha$ such that 
\begin{align}
&xu + yv \leq \alpha \quad \forall (x,y) \in X \quad (Eq 1)\\
&xu + 0v > \alpha \quad \forall (x,0) \in W  \quad (Eq 2)
\end{align}
Then (Eq 2) means 
$$ xu > \alpha \quad \forall x \in \mathbb{R} $$
Now if $u\neq 0$ we can make $x = M(-u)$ for large $M$ to make $xu$ as small as we like,  violating the fact that $xu > \alpha$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.  So we know that $u=0$.  This means that (Eq 2) reduces to 
$$ 0 > \alpha $$
On the other hand (Eq 1) and $u=0$ gives 
$$ yv \leq \alpha  \mbox{ whenever $y \geq e^x$ for some $x \in \mathbb{R}$} $$
In particular: 
$$ e^x v \leq \alpha \quad \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$$
Taking a limit as $x\rightarrow -\infty$ gives
$$ 0 \leq \alpha$$ 
a contradiction.

Comment: Apologies for having written a few false-starts and quickly deleting them.  All of my false-starts were assuming closure of a projection of the set $X$ onto a smaller dimension, which did not necessarily hold.  So, here is a simple counter-example.

Comment: Wait a minute, this counter-example seems almost the same as the counter-example you give at the end of your question...meaning that your own counter-example just needed some small (minor) modification.  Anyway, you would need to given the non-strict inequality to the set $W$ rather than the set $X$.